# Как реализовать табы в Реакте, не используя хуки

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, nextjs

Создал табы на чистом CSS:
https://codepen.io/syberian/pen/RwBBqGq -
и эти табы отлично работают в песочнице.

**HTML**

```
<div class='match-outcome'>
   <ul class='tabs'>
     <li class='tab'>
       <input class='switcher' type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tabs" checked />
       <label for="tab-1">Победы</label>
       <div class="tab-content">
         <p>ПОБЕДЫ.</p>
       </div>
     </li>

     <li class='tab'>
       <input class='switcher' type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tabs" />
       <label for="tab-2">Поражения</label>
       <div class="tab-content">
         <p>ПОРАЖЕНИЯ.</p>
       </div>
     </li>

     <li class=tab>
       <input class='switcher' type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tabs" />
       <label for="tab-3">Ничьи</label>
       <div class="tab-content">
         <p>НИЧЬИ.</p>
       </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**СSS**

```
.match-outcome { 
    max-width: 684px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 6rem 0 2.5rem;
}
    
.tabs {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 315px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    
.tab {
    flex: 1;
}
    
.tab label {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 2rem;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.6s ease;
}
    
.tab label:hover {
    color: lightblue;
}
    
.tab-content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0;
    top: 32px;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    background: #cfc0e3;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease, transform 0.6s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: top center;
}
    
.tab [type=radio] { 
    display: none; 
}
    
.switcher:checked ~ label {
    color: blue;
}
    
.switcher:checked ~ .tab-content {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Но эти табы не работают в Реакте.
Проблема заключается в том что одному из табов в разметке установлен атрибут checked (убрать его я не могу, он задаёт начальный контент, при загрузке странице).
Из-за этого при ререндере компонента, checked всегда стоит на первом табе и вкладки переключаются не корректно.
При нажатии на любую вкладку, кроме первой, переключение почему-то происходит только со ВТОРОГО раза. А при первом нажатии всегда перебрасывает на первую вкладку.

Хуки я не хочу ПОКА использовать, т.к. это реакт-компонент на самом деле будет использоваться в NextJS. И мне почему-то сказали чтобы я пока не использовал хуки, а просто верстал компоненты, без сложной логики.

Есть ли какой-то простой способ решить эту проблему? Можно ли без хуков, написать код на TS который реализует нужный мне функционал табов?
Я пока пытаюсь сообразить, как с помощью TS переключать на каждом табе `checked={true}` и `checked={false}`.

UPD. По просьбам из комментариев, публикую JSX с по сути такой же разметкой как и выше, если не учитывать особенности синтаксиса в реакте. СSS не выкладываю, т.к. он уже выше был скопирован как раз из рабочего проекта.

```
import styles from './Styles.module.css'

<div className={styles['match-outcome']}>
  <ul className={styles.tabs}>
    <li className={styles.tab}>
      <input className={styles.switcher} type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tabs" checked={true} />
      <label htmlFor="tab-1">Победы</label>
      <div className={styles["tab-content"]}>
        <p>ПОБЕДЫ.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    
    <li className={styles.tab}>
       <input className={styles.switcher} type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tabs" />
       <label htmlFor="tab-2">Поражения</label>
       <div className={styles["tab-content"]}>
          <p>ПОРАЖЕНИЯ.</p>
       </div>
     </li>
    
     <li className={styles.tab}>
       <input className={styles.switcher} type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tabs" />
       <label htmlFor="tab-3">Ничьи</label>
       <div className={styles["tab-content"]}>
          <p>НИЧЬИ.</p>
       </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Это хорошо, что вы показали, как у вас работает. Можете теперь показать, как это НЕ работает? Сделайте аналогичную песочницу с вашими попытками. И что вы понимаете под Хуками, которые не хотите использовать? Ведь, по сути, даже useState это хук...

Comment: @SwaD Под хуками я имею ввиду ВСЕ хуки и useState в том числе.
Не корректно работает у меня переключение. Например, чтобы переключится с tab-1 на tab-2 нужно на tab-2 нажать ДВА РАЗА. 
Песочницу с Реактом нет смысла создавать там код будет один в один, как продемонстрировал выше.

Comment: один в один - не будет. Поэтому стоит все-таки добавить. Если вставлять как есть - должно все работать

Comment: @Grundy Ок, раз не верите, сейчас сделаю копипаст прямо из своего рабочего проекта :)

Comment: Выложи это в песочницу, чтобы можно было запустить и посмотреть, например тут https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @Grundy я попробовал это всё дело загрузить в песочницу и в консоли получил вот такое вот сообщение: _Warning: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`._ 
Возможно этого сообщения достаточно чтобы понять в чём проблема, даже не заглядывая в песочницу.

Comment: @TupoScrip, да, этого достаточно :) но отвечающим было бы проще, если бы они это сразу увидели :)

Comment: @Grundy defaultChecked - вот она разгадка на на вопрос :))

Comment: @TupoScrip, расписал в ответе - почему так. Возможно, тебе он не нужен и все исправится само, когда появится состояние внутри твоего компонента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде небольшой конфликт между управляемыми и не управляемыми элементами `input`.

`checked` - используется в управляемых, когда значение устанавливается снаружи. Если в итоге оно будет задаваться через переменные можно так и оставить и все само исправится, когда появится состояние.

Для решения сейчас можно заменить на `defaultChecked` - который используется в неуправляемых компонентах, и состояние инпута хранится внутри него.

Comment: Я просто не догадался в консоль сразу заглянуть :) 
Вижу что компонент в браузере отрендерился и вроде как всё норм.
А в песочнице консоль всё время открыта и там я уже увидел в чём проблема.

Comment: @TupoScrip, если есть возможность в вопросе сразу добавить код который можно запустить и увидеть ошибку, лучше так и делать.

Comment: Понял, в следующий раз так и буду делать :)